# HTML javascript function to create element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this function inside a javascript:

```
function inc(filename) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = filename;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

If I call this function, it will create one element in the DOM. That's fine.
But if I call it another time, I want it to create an element on top of the previous element so that I only have one element created by this funtion in the DOM.
Is it already doing that? If not, how can I make it happen?

I don't understand the DOM very well as you can see by this question.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? A script element is only executed when it's first added to the DOM, so having multiple elements aren't a problem.

Comment: But if you really need to do it, give the element an ID when you create it. Then you can find the old element by ID and delete it before you add the new element.

Comment: check if your element exist first if it doesn't you create it, if it does then change its innerHTML or the attributes you need to change...

Comment: because i have a page with a login. and when i enter chrome asks if I want to remember this data. The thing is that it keeps asking that question everytime that i click a button after the login page

Comment: @alexandre1985: In what way is the code in the question responsible for that browser behavior?

Comment: @David I believe that browser behavior must be because the login page is still inside the DOM structure and it keeps asking that question

Comment: @alexandre1985: You seem to be making some strange assumptions here, and that's really going to make it difficult for you to solve whatever the actual problem is.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you Barman. How can I create an element with an ID inside this function in javascript?

Comment: @David I know. So why does that behaviour keep happening after I skiped(entered) the login page? It must be because the login page still is inside the DOM, right? All my page is in javascript. you can check it out at http://comprasdamonica.hol.es

Comment: You give it an ID with `script.id = "myScriptID";`

Comment: The problem is most likely because you're calling `inc(filename)` multiple times. Each time you call it, it loads the script again and runs the login code.

Comment: @Barman I don't understand. I have call have this 'inc(ctl_base/view/login)' for loading the login and then 'inc(ctl_base/view/main)' for loading the main page. I load main after and if the login is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) When you review the Snippet, you'll have to use the dev tools to see that it worked.

### SNIPPET

```js
function swap(parent, replacement, url) {
  var alpha = document.querySelector(parent);
  var target = alpha.childNodes[0];
  var omega = document.createElement(replacement);
  omega.src = url;
  alpha.replaceChild(omega, target);
}

swap('head', 'script', 'http://end.com');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://beginning.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is completely pointless, you could easily achieve that behavior by changing this line

```
script = document.createElement('script');
```

to

```
script = script || document.createElement('script');
```

Comment: the thing is that the second time it creates, it doesn't know the previous 'script' var because the script var is inside a function

Comment: but it was not defined with `var`, which makes it global.